# Mouse scroll stopped working with Less in Terminal

Tags: terminal, mouse, macos

For a few years now, **Terminal.app** in MacOS has supported mouse-scrolling with the `less` program, but today I noticed that it is no longer accepting mouse scrolls, and only works with the <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> keys now.

---

### What's not working:

**`less`** and all other programs that use it are not accepting mouse scrolls. Instead, it scrolls the terminal window. These 'other' programs are:

- `man`
- `git log`
- `diff`

Previously, `less` would also clear the screen when closing it (`q`), but now the text remains on the screen.

---

### What I've tried:

- **Tested other programs:** `vim` for example, still accepts mouse scrolls
- **Used other Terminal emulators:** `less` is not accepting mouse scrolls on `Hyper` either
- **Tested on another machine over SSH:** Connected to one of my VPSes, and used `less` there within the Terminal app. Mouse-scrolls are working with it.
- **Used a newer version of less:** Installed the latest version (530) of less using **Homebrew**, but it's not working with mouse scrolls either.

So I'm not sure what's wrong. Would greatly appreciate any help to make `less` accept mouse scrolls again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After going through a few other answers, I've realized there is a `$LESS` environment variable that contains default flags.

It's empty on my other Mac and Ubuntu system, but for some reason it's equal to **`-FRX`** on this machine, **and that's causing these issues**:

- `-X` caused it to **NOT** accept mouse scrolls
- `-F` caused it to automatically exit for small files

Which is weird, since I never changed it, so it must've been modified by some other program. Anyways, manually setting it in my `.rc` files fixed the issue:

```
export LESS="-R"
```

---

Sources:

- Unix & Linux: [Neither 'less' or 'less -X' clear screen on exit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156348/neither-less-or-less-x-clear-screen-on-exit)
- SuperUser: [Less command clearing screen upon exit](https://superuser.com/questions/106637/less-command-clearing-screen-upon-exit-how-to-switch-it-off)

Comment: you have my respect. One question - how did you determine, that $LESS had the value of `-FRX` on you computer. I ran `echo $LESS` and it did show the correct value of `-R`. Nevertheless, I added `export LESS="-R"` to `.zshrc` and this did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're using `less` inside `git` (through `git log` or similar):

[git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corepager) docs have the answer:

> **When the `LESS` environment variable is unset, Git sets it to `FRX` (if `LESS` environment variable is set, Git does not change it at all).** If you want to selectively override Git’s default setting for `LESS`, you can set `core.pager` to e.g. `less -S`. This will be passed to the shell by Git, which will translate the final command to `LESS=FRX less -S`. The environment does not set the `S` option but the command line does, instructing less to truncate long lines. Similarly, setting `core.pager` to `less -+F` will deactivate the `F` option specified by the environment from the command-line, deactivating the "quit if one screen" behavior of `less`.

(emphasis mine)

TLDR:

- `git` is the one setting `$LESS` environment variable to `FRX` if empty
- scrolling in `less` [doesn't work with `X` option set](https://superuser.com/a/972232/440801)
- unset the default `X` option with `git config --global --add core.pager "less -+X"`